# Using ether.js to call a mint function that requires ETH

Tags: ethereumjs

I wrote a ERC721 contract with a mint function that requires you send 0.x ETH when you call the mint function.

How do I call this function with 0.x ETH? I am still writing the unit test for this. If the mint function does not check for msg.value, I can just call the mint function like
contract.mint(), but when my mint function does require msg.value, I can't find a way to add ETH to my call.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Nvm. You need to pass the override permission in the function call. Missed this in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

mint() needs to be modified by payable.

contract.mint({value:ethers.BigNumber.from("100")})